# Regarding modifications in three20 library

Tags: iphone, three20

Is there anyone know how to edit three20 library?
I have integrated three20 library into my project but I want to small images first but in my project first it shows big images and when I touch on see all then it shows all images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some reading of the [docs](http://three20.info/documentation).